# How to get data between range of dates in SQL Server over 1 year combining 2 tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, range, date-range

There are 2 tables -

1. Sales table with details of order_number, item_number and sale_date.
2. Promotions table with details of item_number, promotion_start_date and promotion_end_date.

Promotions run all through the year over a range of days. **Need is to extract list of items sold when no promotion was running**.

Need to extract only the order numbers between

- "first promotion_end_date" and "second promotion_start_date" then
- "second promotion_end_date" and "third promotion_start_date" then
- "third promotion_end_date" and "fourth promotion_start_date" and so on.

Sample tables are as follows -

**1) Promotions table** : ( When promotion_end_date is 'Null', promotion is still 'ACTIVE')

| item_number | promotion_start_date | promotion_end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC0001 | 12-31-2020 | 01-19-2021 |
| ABC0001 | 03-01-2021 | 03-31-2021 |
| ABC0005 | 02-05-2021 | 03-01-2021 |
| ABC0002 | 06-01-2021 | 07-31-2021 |
| ABC0001 | 09-31-2021 | 11-05-2021 |
| ABC0001 | 11-08-2021 | Nil |

**2) Sales Table** :

| order_number | item_number | sale_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 110000011 | ABC0001 | 01-18-2021 |
| 110000012 | ABC0001 | 01-31-2021 |
| 110000013 | ABC0002 | 06-30-2021 |
| 110000014 | ABC0001 | 07-31-2021 |
| 110000015 | ABC0005 | 04-05-2021 |
| 110000016 | ABC0001 | 10-05-2021 |
| 110000017 | ABC0001 | 12-01-2021 |
| 110000018 | ABC0002 | 08-30-2021 |
| 110000019 | ABC0001 | 04-01-2021 |
| 110000020 | ABC0001 | 07-30-2021 |
| 110000021 | ABC0005 | 02-28-2021 |
| 110000022 | ABC0001 | 11-06-2021 |

**3) Expected Result :**

| order_number | item_number | sale_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 110000012 | ABC0001 | 01-31-2021 |
| 110000014 | ABC0001 | 07-31-2021 |
| 110000015 | ABC0005 | 04-05-2021 |
| 110000017 | ABC0001 | 12-01-2021 |
| 110000018 | ABC0002 | 08-30-2021 |
| 110000019 | ABC0001 | 04-01-2021 |
| 110000020 | ABC0001 | 07-30-2021 |
| 110000022 | ABC0001 | 11-06-2021 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [many ways to solve this kind of problem](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join) but I generally prefer `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT order_number, item_number, sale_date
FROM dbo.Sales AS s
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1 
    FROM dbo.Promotions AS p
    WHERE s.item_number = p.item_number
    AND s.sale_date >= p.promotion_start_date
    AND s.sale_date <= COALESCE(p.promotion_end_date, GETDATE())
);
```

I think the trickiest part here is substituting the end date with a valid point in time when the promotion is ongoing.

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1098160a027743fd2d5ccdc19f4dcf02) which shows how we love to see table structure and sample data and also corrects September 31st.